# The "SELECT" request is in disorder despite the use of "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty confused about this problem. My database (~20,000,000 lines) sends me bad results when I try to sort in the request.

Here an example of query:

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE id = 163 AND time >= '2019-04-06 12:55:01.000' 
AND time <= '2019-04-06 13:09:00.000' ORDER BY 'time' ASC LIMIT 9000;
```

And this give me :

[image: issue]

It's not completly in disorder, but more like by "group" misordered.

I tried to remove and add new indexes in my time column but nothing works.

```
| values | 1 | index_valuetime | 1 | time | A | 3307869 | NULL | NULL |  | 
BTREE |||
```

Also :
- I noticed that ASC and DESC were producing the same result. 
- The disorder are every time in the same values of the database, even if I change my query.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'time'`. You're ordering by the string, `'time'` rather than the column `time`. All rows return equivalent values for a string, so they are sorted by default order.

Comment: what is the data type

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, the data type of 'time' is clearly string ;-)

Comment: Thanks you guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have this:

```
ORDER BY 'time' ASC
```

you need this

```
ORDER BY time ASC
```